# Where do you store the result of a MIPS program?

Tags: mips, fibonacci

I've written a code generator for the 32-bit MIPS architecture. To test it, I've written an algorithm that returns the Nth number in the Fibonacci sequence. Does it matter where the result is returned to?

Comment: That depends. If you're just calling your assembly function from another assembly function of yours then it doesn't matter that much. Typically you'd use `$v0` for return values, though.